# Importing separate html assets from external file

Tags: javascript, dynamic, assets, html-imports, html5-template

Let's say I have an html page (assets.html)  that has a few custom elements like buttons on it. The buttons are composed of html/css and an image.

Is it possible to import "assets.html" and 'grab' the button and clone/copy it and place it into the page that accessed assets.html?

I want to be able to have a page that has a lot of interface components, be able to load that page and grab any component I want from it.

Is it possible? What method would guarantee the css and image would be preserved with the imported html?

Comment: Is this what you mean http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp?

Comment: @AntonioHernández Yeah, that's one option, use something built around XHR. I'm not sure how css and images are brought in with it but I believe it works. I don't really want the imported page to be visible, just the elements in it when I clone and place them. Maybe an iframe would work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML Imports**

You can use [HTML Imports](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/) to import an external HTML page. Put the link in the head of your main document.

```
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="assets.html" id="assets">
</head>
```

The imported document is parsed at download (and scripts inside it are executed) but the elements are not imported in the DOM tree. Instead it is stocked in the form of an HTML Document.

Then you can grab any elements within the imported document using the `import` property of the `<link>` element. Use `cloneNode(true)` to get a deep copy of the imported asset.

```
<script>
    var importedDoc = document.querySelector( 'link#assets' ).import
    var button = importedDoc.querySelector( 'button#btn1' ).cloneNode( true )
</script>
```

You can the add the cloned element to the main document using `appendChild()`.

You can also import a `<style>` element to get CSS assets:

```
document.head.appendChild( importedDoc.querySelector( 'style#st1' ).cloneNode( true ) )
```

*Note:* HTML Imports is a W3C editor's draft implemented natively in Chrome and Opera. There's [a polyfill](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/html-imports/) from the [WebComponents.js team](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) available for other browsers.

---

**HTML Template**

You can also import multiple elements at once by putting them in a [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element. Clone the `content` property of the `<template>` element:

```
<template id="templ1">
    <style>
       #btn2 { color: red ; }
    </style>
    Name: <input id="name1">
    <button id="btn2" onclick="alert('Hello '+name1.value)">Say Hello</button>
</template>

<script>
    var template = importedDoc.querySelector( '#templ1' )
    document.body.appendChild( template.content.cloneNode( true ) )
</script>
```

```js
var template = document.querySelector( '#templ1' )
document.body.appendChild( template.content.cloneNode( true ) )
```

```html
<template id="templ1">
    <style>
       button { color: red ; }
    </style>
    Name: <input id="name1">
    <button onclick="alert('Hello '+name1.value)">Say Hello</button>
</template>
```

Comment: Your suggestions are from the Web Components API -- is that correct? In the case of Templates -- A template exists in the DOM as soon as you reference it in the html. Using an iFrame, I was removing the iFrame once I had cloned the elements out of it. With Import, the elements in the imported page are not automatically put into the DOM...which is better, but Import has less browser support. The polyfill looks like it covers the problems. Can you just clarify there -- then I'll mark yours as the correct answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Yes it's correct... even if the Web Components term has less sense now that Shadow Dom and Custom Elements are part of the  DOM and HTML Living Strandard, and Template is part af the HTML5 W3C standard.